# CoroutineScope with SupervisorJob vs supervisorScope

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

Recently I've been learning coroutines in detail, as I understand `SupervisorJob()` gives us opportunity to not cancel all children if one of the children of coroutine is cancelled due to some reason.

It is said that coroutines started with `coroutineScope` will cancel all children if one fails, but the ones started with `supervisorScope` will only cancel the child which is failed

I wonder if I could change behaviour of `CoroutineScope` by adding `SupervisorJob` as CoroutineContext to it, but I couldn't get expected behaviour which is the thing I don't get

**Expected behaviour - getData1() and getData3() result gets printed***

***Actual: - getData2() cancels all coroutine***

```
fun main() = runBlocking {

    val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { coroutineContext, throwable ->
        println(throwable)
    }

    val customScope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + exceptionHandler)


    customScope.launch {
        launch {
            getData1().also { println(it) }
        }
        launch {
            getData2().also { println(it) }
        }
        launch {
            getData3().also { println(it) }
        }
     }.join()

}


private suspend fun getData1(): String? {
    delay(1000)
    return "data 1"
}

private suspend fun getData2(): String? {
    delay(300)
    throw RuntimeException("While getting Data 2 exception happened")
}

private suspend fun getData3(): String? {
    delay(800)
    return "data 3"
}
```

Answer (score 8):

> It is said that coroutines started with coroutineScope will cancel all children if one fails, but the ones started with supervisorScope will only cancel the child which is failed

That's right, but what you're trying to do is create only 1 child of supervisorScope.

[image]

```
customScope.launch {
    launch {
        // some work
    }
    launch {
        throw RuntimeException()
    }
    launch {
        // some work
    }
 }
```

What you actually need is some thing like this:

[image]

```
customScope.launch {
    // some work  
}
customScope.launch {
    throw RuntimeException()
}
customScope.launch {
    // some work    
}
```

This is how paren-child relationship works when creating new coroutines

> The new coroutine creates its own child Job instance (using a job from this context as its parent) and defines its child context as a parent context plus its job:

To understand how this works in details I suggest reading this [article](https://elizarov.medium.com/coroutine-context-and-scope-c8b255d59055).

Answer (score 2):

The main key difference between SupervisorJob and a regular Job is that the **Direct** children of a supervisor job can fail independently of each other.

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() {

    val handler =
        CoroutineExceptionHandler { context, throwable -> println("throwable: $throwable, jobContext: ${context[Job]}") }

    val context = Job() + Dispatchers.Default + handler
    val scope = CoroutineScope(context)
    with(scope) {
        launch {
            delay(300)
            throw Exception("Coroutine 1 failed")
        }

        launch {
            delay(400)
            println("Coroutine 2 finished")
        }

    }
    
    Thread.sleep(3000)
}
```

If you run this example the second coroutine doesn't finish it's execution and it gets cancelled but if you change the Job with SupervisorJob, the second coroutine will finish it work without a problem. It also explain how supervisorScope works. the **Direct** children of supervisorScope can fail independently of each other.

Answer (score 0):

You are not launching the three inner coroutines in `customScope`. You're launching them in the scope of the launched outer coroutine (by using implicit `this` to launch them). If you launch them from that custom scope that has a SupervisorJob, then it should work:

```
launch {
    listOf(
        customScope.launch {
            getData1().also { println(it) }
        },
        customScope.launch {
            getData2().also { println(it) }
        },
        customScope.launch {
            getData3().also { println(it) }
        }
    ).joinAll()
}.join()
```

Comment: not working, no output

Comment: Oops. We also need to wait for the child coroutines! See updated code.

Comment: now it works, but still I can't get the topic, I have drawn structure of job as image on link (https://ibb.co/kmqRPYy), in this way, if one of the jobs on bottom get cancels, then it should look to its parent, if it is ordinary job then all children should be cancelled which will be, but if i make customScope.launch(SupervisorJob()) it shouldn't cancel other children but it cancels

Comment: pls inform me if I am drawing structure not correctly, at least you can draw your own structure and send here

Comment: Your diagram looks correct. I don’t understand exactly what arrangement you’re describing that you don’t understand.

Answer (score -2):

the SupervisorJob expected behaviour, happens when we call it with the lunch/async from the root scope .

```
val job1 =rootscope.lunch{}
val job2 =rootscope.lunch{}
val job3 =rootscope.lunch{}
```

if one of these jobs failed, it will not affect others,
***However* if we use it as a child its acts like a Job() like your example**.

**but what if i need child's coroutines behave as "if it lunched from a root scope" ?** . like your example, then supervisorScope appear to solve this problem, if u use :

```
      customScope.launch {
        supervisorScope {
            launch {

                throw Exception()
            }
            launch {
                println("hjkhjk 111")
            }
            launch {
                println("hjkhjk 222")
            }
        }
    }.join()
```

then every child coroutines runs as rootScope.lunch{...} , and your problem will be solved

Comment: the answer is right stop making the down-arrow pls